# Create edgelist from a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionaries with the following structure:

```
1:{'Amendment': '1', 
   'status': 'Stadf\xc3\xa6stet', 
   'Name': 'Bodil Kornbek', 
   'title': 'L 1 Forslag til till\xc3\xa6gsbevillingslov for 2004.', 
   'fremsat': '2005-03-04', 
   'Vote.Numeric': '2', 
   'PSession': '1', 
   'vedtaget': '2005-04-12', 
   'Lsession': '3', 
   'Voteid': '38', 
   'Month': '4', 
   'Year': '2005', 
   'Vote': 'Frav\xc3\xa6rende', 
   'Party': 'KD', 
   'Law': 'L 1', 
   'ministerie': 'Finansministeriet'}
```

the keys range from 1 to ca. 500000, and each nested dictionary contains information about one member of the Danish parliament on one vote. Furthermore there is information that identifies the unique vote on which the member voted. I would like for each member to extract all the votes on which that member was active, and compare that members voting behavior to all other members that were active on the same subset of votes, iteratively.

Ideally for each member I would compare that member to one other member on the votes where they were active, and calculate the proportion of votes where they voted the same to all of their common votes. If the proportion is larger than, say, .65 then the pair gets added to a list.

So the end results should be a list with the format:

```
[member1, member2
 member1, member4
 member1, member7
 member2, member5
 etc..
]
```

I can anyone show me how this could be done in python?

Comment: I think your question is rather unclear. The complete content of your nested dictionary is rather irrelevant for the question. Do you have a data-structure where your members are actually listed?

Comment: What identifies a member uniquely? The name, or something else?

Comment: @Karl: the variables that identify a member is simply the name, there are no members with the same name.

Comment: @Alex: I have the data in a csv file, where each row is the content of one nested dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's transform the data (I will make some assumptions here) so that the keys of the dictionary are the members of parliament (identified by `Name`), and the data for each is a mapping of how they voted (`Vote.Numeric`) on each issue (`Voteid`), so the `Voteid`s are keys in that sub-dictionary. We can discard the rest of the information as irrelevant.

The non-fancy procedural way:

```
member_to_votes = defaultdict(dict)
for item in vote_data:
    member_to_votes[item['Name']][item['Voteid']] = item['Vote.Numeric']
```

Now let's define the similarity between two voting records:

```
def votes_agree(member_a, member_b, threshold):
    # Find the union of issues they voted on...
    issues = set(member_a.keys()).union(member_b.keys())
    # See how many of these they voted the same way on (we use a placeholder
    # if one member did not vote on the issue, so that they automatically
    # disagree) and compare the fraction of agreeing votes to the threshold.
    # There is a little hack in here: `True` is 1 in a numeric context, and
    # `False` is zero, so we can add up the boolean results directly.
    return sum(
        member_a.get(issue, None) == member_b.get(issue, None)
        for issue in issues
    ) / float(len(issues)) >= threshold
```

Now we can create all pairs of members and see which ones agree:

```
def agreeing_members(member_to_votes, threshold):
    return [
        [a, b] for a, b in itertools.combinations(member_to_votes.keys(), 2)
        if votes_agree(member_to_votes[a], member_to_votes[b], threshold)
    ]
```

Comment: But it would be better to create `member_to_votes` directly from the CSV file, if you can see how... :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Karl! Whenever i try to run defaultdict(dict), I get the message: TypeError: first argument must be callable

Comment: Strange. What version of Python are you using? It works for me. Have you perhaps reused `dict` as a variable name somewhere? Don't do that; it's the name of a built-in (the type of dict objects).

Comment: Figured out how to create the members_to_votes list from the csv file, thanks a lot Karl - this works beautifully and saved me a lot of time!